# asp.net core 2 authorization Logout MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I currently authenticate my starting View of my MVC Application by adding the following Code to my Controller and it works great.

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Domain Users")]
```

Im wondering if there is also something that allows you to log out of that authorization again. Havent found anything regarding it so far, anyone worked with it before?

Comment: Clear question is not clear about what you actually wanting? Please describe it properly.

Comment: Im wanting baisicly a button to log out the currently authorized user.

Comment: Doesn't this come out of the box with the ASP.NET template in Visual Studio when configured with authentication? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/asp.net_core/asp.net_core_log_in_and_log_out.htm

Comment: ill check this out thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what i used in a asp.net core 2.2 project of mine.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Website.DAL.Models.Users

@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager


           <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="ml-auto">
                <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">
                    <li><button type="submit" class="fa fa-sign-out btn btn-w-m btn-link">Logout</button></li>
                </ul>
            </form>
```

However it is logingout the entire user. As far i know there is now way to unsubsribe a user or something like that.

Comment: hmm that seems interessting ill try it. And yeah I just need to be able to got that user out again.

Comment: Please keep in mind that some paths might be different for you!

Comment: Are you doing anything „special“ in the controller with it?

Comment: No i do not, it is calling the logout function in the Account controller. The Account controller is there by default. If not it might be possible that you need to scaffold the item. To do that see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio